# Cross-platform C# application using Mono with nice UI

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, mono

I want to create a cross-platform C# application using Mono.

I used to think that for these purposes I need to use GTK#, Now it seems to me that it is not as attractive to users as I had thought before.
A good choice would be a Silverlight (Moonlight), but it's
solution for WEB and despite the fact that it can be run outside of the browser, I think that this technology not completely suitable for my purposes. I think WPF would be a great choice,
but Mono does not support it.

So I'm looking for cross-platform gui toolkit for C# to build applications with powerful, animated and custom user interface.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming ;-). You have just stumbled upon a problem that many of us share. You can either go with GTK# OR create libraries for the logic and create a gui for each platform.

Comment: I don't like Java, but I'm convinced that I should use Java if I would ever want to create multi-platform apps.

Comment: Have you looked into XWT? https://github.com/mono/xwt

Comment: or https://github.com/picoe/Eto and also GTK# can be pimped to look acceptable...

Comment: I'm a little biased, but I like Qt, and someone made a wrapper for it to Mono/.NET, you could try that, but I can't attest to it (I've only used the C++ versions): https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp

Comment: I don't think you should invest much time learning silverlight if you don't know it because it is dying these days. If I were you I would try to achieve my goal using javascript and asp.net MVC. ASP.NET is going to be supported in Linux and MAC soon so a local host web app may be a nice solution and JS is very popular as u know.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/). It's probably the best solution for cross-platform C#, but also very expensive.

I suggest regular .NET WinForms. Silverlight is not a good option, Microsoft is not actively promoting it and WPF has currently few benefits compared to winforms (it's future is also debated).

Comment: Especially since OP mentions WPF/Silverlight. MVVMCross is a similar framework/toolkit for mobile development.

Comment: Ok, added reasons why WPF and Silverlight are bad choices.

Comment: @Sire Ok, thanks. I think I will use this bundle - Mono(for cross-platform app) version of WinForms just with Awesomium (for nice GUI) in the window.
Is this a good choice?

Comment: @user2656632 Never tried Awesomium. It's quite a different thing to create a UI with just HTML. I would start with WinForms, but compare the two and see what suits you.